# Box2D detecting one way collision for round objects

Tags: c++, listener, box2d, collision

I am new to Box2D and is currently trying to detect if an object (Ball) has managed to pass through another object (Goal) by using `b2Contact`. For this, I have implemented `b2ContactListener` and everything is working fine.

However, I was wondering, is there any way for me to set to detect collision for one direction only? For example, only from left to right, collision will not count if the ball passes through from right to left. I want to implement something like this from [here](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/one-way-walls) as could be seen from the documentation.

In the documentation, they have detected the direction of the collision by using the points from the object as such

```
int numPoints = contact->GetManifold()->pointCount;
b2WorldManifold worldManifold;
contact->GetWorldManifold( &worldManifold );
```

However, for my case, I am using a `b2CircleShape` for my ball object, which indirectly returns the numPoints to be 0. Thus, I am unable to detect the collision using the above method. Is there any way I could detect the points from the circle? Or is there any way I could detect the direction of the collision?

Comment: Maybe you could take into account the relative velocity of the objects, and their positions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

```
b2WorldManifold manifold;
contact->GetWorldManifold(&manifold);
manifold.normal.Normalize();
if(manifold.normal.x > 0){
   [...]
}
```